# How to change the border color of bootstrap table using inline css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Although `inline css` is not recommended but I just want to test it in one special case and hence want to override the default border color of a `bootstrap table` to white. But the following does not work. It still displays the default border color of a bootstrap table. How can it be achieved or what are other alternatives **without** using javascript or **without** messing around with default bootstrap css?

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="border-color:white;">
...
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using only `style="border-color:white;"` sets the table border to white but they are being overwritten by the `th` and `td` styles.

You have to set it for every `th` and `td` too. If you are using only only Inline css then that will be time consuming. The easier way would be to include the styles in css and use direct-child sign (`>`) to give the style preference. Like this.

```
table.table-bordered > thead > tr > th{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Here is a working snippet :

```css
table.table-bordered{
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin-top:20px;
  }
table.table-bordered > thead > tr > th{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
table.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way is to add your own CSS file, with custom changes, after bootstrap default CSS. Not sure about version you use, but this is how applying of border looks in 3.3.7, and you have to overwrite that rule:

```
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th, .table-bordered > thead > tr > td, .table-bordered > thead > tr > th {
    border: 1px solid red; //your desired color
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/T5xU5ismja

Comment: Best answer I found readin here quickly. It not only changes the header as the answer that was chosen does.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the elements inside that have the border, in which case the inline style needs to be applied to the element that has the border, like the `td`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-color:white;">asdf</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only target the table header use the following code:-

http://www.bootply.com/oAYBUqQet3

```
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > th {
     border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
table.table-bordered{
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin-top:20px;
  }
table.table-bordered > thead > tr > th{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
table.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
table.table-bordered{
    border:1px solid blue!important;
    margin-top:20px;
  }
table.table-bordered > thead > tr > th{
    border:1px solid blue!important;
}
table.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td{
    border:1px solid blue!important;
}
```